# Taking input in java from console

Tags: java, user-input

I am a C/C++ programmer and new in java.

```
char input1[13],input2[20]; 

 int a,b;

while(scanf("%s %s %d %d",input1,input2,&a,&b)!=EOF)
{
    printf("%s %s %d %d",input1,input2,a,b);
}
```

Can anyone help me transform the above c code to java?
thanks

Comment: Take a look at the Scanner class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Input stream is called `stdin`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to Java, I think it'll be more benificial to give you references to sources than a full solution!

[You can use the Scanner class to read user input.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

[You can use System.out for output.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

As for the types, you can pretty much use the same thing, but I would suggest you use the String class instead of char[].

Hope this helps.